# How to inject BotAuthentication into the controller

Tags: botframework

I am seeking help to use BotAuthentication through injection, so that I can use the secrets from keyvault to pass the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword.
Thanks.

I am using BotBuilder V3.15.3, which allows me to use BotAuthentication and pass the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword as the parameters. But since, I have these values fetched from keyvault, I am unable to use the annotation, because I cannot read the keyvault as const. There is another provision by using CredentialProviderType, which takes ICredentialProvider type. 
[BotAuthentication(CredentialProviderType = typeof(CustomCredentialProvider))]
But, this type does not take appId as parameter. How do I inject appId and appPassword into it?

```
///Controller code

[BotAuthentication(CredentialProviderType =typeof(NewStaticCredentialProvider))]

public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {}

///CredentialProvider code

public interface ICredentialProvider

{

        Task<bool> IsValidAppIdAsync(string appId);

        Task<string> GetAppPasswordAsync(string appId);

        Task<bool> IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync();
    }

    public class SimpleCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider
    {
        public string AppId { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public Task<bool> IsValidAppIdAsync(string appId)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(appId == AppId);
        }

        public Task<string> GetAppPasswordAsync(string appId)
        {
            return Task.FromResult((appId == this.AppId) ? this.Password : null);
        }

        public Task<bool> IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppId));
        }
    }

    public sealed class NewStaticCredentialProvider : SimpleCredentialProvider
    {
        public NewStaticCredentialProvider(string appId, string password)
        {
            this.AppId = Secrets.MicrosoftAppId;
            this.Password = Secrets.MicrosoftAppPassword;
        }
    }
```

In the annotation, I do not see a way to pass the app id and password.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution. The problem was that I had my own interface with same name ICredentialProvider because of which it couldn't resolve the instance. I kept only SimpleCredentialProvider class and changed that to some other name. And bingo!